# Ordering flexbox element makes the container fail to fill the screen

Tags: css, flexbox

Everything in this set-up works great, if I leave the order un-changed (I want 30% width for the picture, 70% for the text, as set).  The problem is, I want the picture on the right side of the page, so I add "order:1" to the picture, but then the picture has blank space to its right (keeping the container from appearing to fill the page on large screens).  I tried setting margins and padding to auto to no avail. Thanks for the help!

```css
    .communityoutreachrow {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }
    
    .communityoutreachimg {
        width:30%;
      order:1;
        
    }
    .communityoutreachtext {
        width:70%;
    }
    .communityoutreachimg img{
        border-radius:1em;
        border:.15em solid white;
    }
    .communityoutreachtext {
        margin-right:1em;
    }
    .communityoutreachimg p {
    text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="communityoutreachrow"><div class="communityoutreachimg">
    <img src="https://www.bakashana.org//wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DSC02149-300x200.jpg" alt="A young couple receives condoms after getting tested for HIV" class="size-medium wp-image-2962" /> <p>A young couple receives condoms after testing for HIV</p></div><div class="communityoutreachtext">
    <p>In Collaboration with <a href="/our-partners">MTV's Staying Alive Fund</a>, and <a href="/our-partners">Amplify Change</a>, Bakashana has been providing health outreach services to communities around Kasama since 2016. These services include HIV/AIDs Voluntary Care, Testing, and Planning (VCT), and sensitizations and trainings regarding sexual and reproductive health and rights.  These outreach programs are part of Bakashana's strategy to empower youth, and especially women, to know their rights and utilize their agency to create brighter futures.</p></div></div>
```

Comment: Add `width: 100%` for **.communityoutreachimg img**. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to give your `img` tag a width of `100%` to fill the space.

```css
.communityoutreachrow {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.communityoutreachimg {
  width:30%;
  order:1;

}
.communityoutreachtext {
  width:70%;
}
.communityoutreachimg img{
  /* add this to have image fill the space */
  width: 100%;
  border-radius:1em;
  border:.15em solid white;
}
.communityoutreachtext {
  margin-right:1em;
}
.communityoutreachimg p {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="communityoutreachrow"><div class="communityoutreachimg">
    <img src="https://www.bakashana.org//wp-content/uploads/2016/11/DSC02149-300x200.jpg" alt="A young couple receives condoms after getting tested for HIV" class="size-medium wp-image-2962" /> <p>A young couple receives condoms after testing for HIV</p></div><div class="communityoutreachtext">
    <p>In Collaboration with <a href="/our-partners">MTV's Staying Alive Fund</a>, and <a href="/our-partners">Amplify Change</a>, Bakashana has been providing health outreach services to communities around Kasama since 2016. These services include HIV/AIDs Voluntary Care, Testing, and Planning (VCT), and sensitizations and trainings regarding sexual and reproductive health and rights.  These outreach programs are part of Bakashana's strategy to empower youth, and especially women, to know their rights and utilize their agency to create brighter futures.</p></div></div>
```